# Using the AWS control panel interface for launching instances, how do you access instance storage?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have launched a default EC2 instance, the [cr1.8xlarge](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) instance type that includes `240 GB of SSD instance storage`, using the [AWS control panel](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home).

I have also started and connected to the instance.  I attempted with both the `Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Base` default AMI provided in the "Quick Launch" list in the Amazon control panel "Launch" dialog, and with the `Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 LTS for Cluster Instances` default AMI from the same list.  For both AMI's, I and attempted to access the noted 240 GB of SSD instance storage from within the running OS.  Again, I used the AWS control panel both to launch, and to start, the instances.

I cannot find the advertised 240 GB SSD storage either on the Windows, or on the Ubuntu image.  (For Windows, there is no drive other than the root C: drive listed; for Ubuntu, there is nothing listed in the /mnt directory except for "lost & found".)

How can I access the 240 GB of SSD instance storage that is supposedly available for my running cr1.8xlarge instance?  I would like to be able to do so using the AWS control panel and/or directly from within the running instances, if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. **This is not a forum.** In particular, it's not the Amazon AWS forum, where your very basic questions would be much better suited -- _after_ you read the documentation, of course.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks, Michael.  I have carefully read all AWS documentation.  Are amazon-ec2-tagged questions not appropriate on ServerFault?

Comment: It's interesting that well-defined questions, even if basic, are considered to be "bad" questions.  To me, this is typically an indication of a user who is an expert in one domain, and never ventures out of that domain; thereby assuming that only experts can ask legitimate questions.

Comment: You don't appear to have actually read the documentation, your comments notwithstanding.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Indeed, I have read the documentation.  The documentation states that instance stores need to be added.  However, as noted in my comments below, the "instance store" tab is disabled.  I know I can use EC2 command-line tools, but as my question attempts to make clear, I would like to know if it is possible to accomplish this directly through the AWS control panel.

Comment: Note to downvoters: In fact, the "Quick Launch" AWS tool does not support mounting instance stores.  One must use the "Classic" tool.  It decisively does not state this in the documentation.  Therefore, on its face, this is a reasonable and fair question to ask - with a trivial answer (that I suspect you do not know yourselves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which create method you use, there should already be an attached Ephemeral store.

If you're using the Classic Wizard, the Instance stores are mounted during the "Instance Details" stage, right after you select network. For that type of instance, you have up to four devices.

To add them after creation requires the use of the API or the CLI tools.

Comment: Thanks.  I used the "Quick Launch" wizard.  Within this wizard, in the "Edit Details" -> "Storage Device Configuration" section, the "Instance Store Volumes" tab is disabled; this is where I suspected I should set these settings.

Comment: Indeed - the Classic Wizard must be used to launch the AMI, rather than the "Quick Launch" wizard.  The quick launch wizard does not allow you to map an instance store.